# Wierd Errors: Not on any other page with same code on lines

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to convert from mysql to mysqli and I have been having some problems. I have been able to fix most of them, but some I have not. This is one of them. This is the only file that I have seen this on. I have to test some yet, but so far this is the only one. How do I resolve those errors? I have not been able to find anything. Please note that it was working just fine with mysql. Any help is appreciated.

With error reporting on, this is what I get.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in <path to file> on line 16

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in <path to file> on line 36
```

For easier viewing, this is line 16

```
 if ($link->connect_errno > 0){
```

and this is line 36

```
$admincheck = $link->query($adminchecksql);
```

Here is the file

```
<head>
<title>User Processing</title>
    <body bgcolor="#9966FF">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="path to favicon"/>
</head>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('DB_NAME', 'DB Name');
define('DB_USER', 'DB USER');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DB Password');
define('DB_HOST', 'DB Host');


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($link->connect_errno > 0){
die('Could not connect: ' .$link->connect_error());
}

if ($_POST['password']!=$_POST['confirmpass']){
    echo "That passwords entered do not match, please use your browser's back button and try again.";

}else{
    $fname = $_POST['First_Name'];
    $lname = $_POST['Last_Name'];
    $usid = $_POST['user_id'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];
    $admins = $_POST['isadmin'];
    $admin_user_id = $_POST['your_user_id'];
    $admin_pass = $_POST['your_password'];
    $table = "tc_".$usid;
   $isadmincheck = "yes";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tc_users (FirstName, LastName, userid, password, isadmin) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$usid', '$pword', '$admins')";
    $newtable = "CREATE TABLE $table (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, time datetime NOT NULL,punchtype VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,groupname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, dept VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, notes VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    $adminchecksql = "SELECT * FROM tc_users WHERE userid = '$admin_user_id' and password = '$admin_pass' and isadmin = '$isadmincheck'";
    $admincheck = $link->query($adminchecksql);
    if ($admincheck->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, you are not an administrator or your username and password were not correct. so this will not work,";
    }else{
        $sqlquery = $link->query($sql);
        $tablequery = $link->query($newtable);
        echo "User " . $usid . " added successfully.";
    } 

}
$link->close();
?>
<form method="GET" action="<path to add new user page>">
<input type="submit" value="Add New User">
</form> 
<form method="GET" action="<path to user administration page>">
<input type="submit" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Comment: Isn't this `$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);` suppose to be `$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`?

Comment: thank you. I have edited about 60 files so far, so I have missed some of the little but yet most important things. Thank you again.

Comment: Please create answer so we can close it properly.

Comment: @AdamMiller : why do you have `<body>` inside `<head>`??

Comment: That is just to change the background color. It works, but I just accidentally put it there and I never took it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_*` functions use an old MySQL API which is not Object Oriented amongst many other things, and you are trying to use that using OOP syntax later in your code; hence the error.

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($link->connect_errno > 0){        // Na Na, No such property

}
```

Most probably, you were looking for [**mysqli**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect)

```
$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Indeed I was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

To this

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

You're missing the `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: new mysqli also works and that is what I meant to put. I am editing about 60 files and just missed a small but important piece there. Thank you.